# Exporting xcarchive and IPA in xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, command-line

I want to make build scripts for my app to export xcarchive and ipa files.

I used following command to export xcarchive:

```
xcodebuild -scheme myscheme archive -archivePath path/appname.xcarchive
```

Which gave me an xcarchive file and I used following to export IPA file:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat IPA -exportProvisioningProfile *** -archivePath path/appname.xcarchive -exportPath path/appname.ipa
```

And I got following error regardless of what I typed in front of *exportProvisioningProfile*.
no provisioning profile matches ***

** EXPORT FAILED **

What should I write insted of *** in front of *exportProvisioningProfile*?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the provisioning profile. This is the same name as seen on the page (https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action). If you have spaces in that name you need to write the name with quotes. E.g.

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat IPA -archivePath
          MyMobileApp.xcarchive -exportPath MyMobileApp.ipa
          -exportProvisioningProfile 'MyMobileApp Distribution Profile'
```

It may also be that you have not downloaded the provisioning profile, try re-downloading it and opening it with Xcode to install it in the correct location.

Comment: This helped me indirectly (I had a different problem, needed to build outside of XCode). But I had to remove the `.ipa` at the `exportPath` option because it was confusing Transporter; the actual ipa file would be inside this folder.